# How to switch the order in which objects appear

Tags: cut-copy-paste, replace, filetype-tex, find

I have a custom command in a TeX file which takes two inputs `A` and `B`, let's call it `\operation{A}{B}`.
I want to

1. find all of the instances of `\operation` where the first entry `A` starts with the string `e_`, then
2. (only in those instances) swap the contents of the first entry `A` with the second entry `B`.

The result of this command should ensure that there are no instances of `\operation` where its first entry starts with `e_` (We can assume that it does not appear in both arguments `A` and `B` within the file.)

I can't figure out a way to do this using `:%s` command. Any other assistance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work. We'll use capture groups (`\(\)`) and back-references (`\1`,`\2`) to do the swap, and the right pattern to find all the right places.

This one I wrote from scratch, but if I wasn't sure to get it right I would first search interactively (or using `:global`) until I got the right pattern, then use `:%substitute//...` to re-use the pattern.

```
%substitute/\\operation{\(e_[^}]*\)}{\([^}]*\)}/\\operation{\2}{\1}
```

Add `/g` if you have more than one on a line.

We use `[^}]*` to simulate a non-greedy `.*` (vim can do this with `.\{-}`), but in this case we really only want until the next `}`. If `A` and `B` can contain nested `{}`, which is generally true in LaTeX, you might have better luck with `.*` or `.\{-}`, or you might need something far more sophisticated. An example:

```
global/\\operation{e_/normal! 0f{di{;vi{p%,p
```

Breakdown:

- `:global/\\operation{e_/`: for every line matching the pattern
- `:normal!`: do these normal mode key-strokes without mappings
- `0f{di{`: delete the first argument
- `;vi{p`: paste it over the second
- `%,p`: paste the second argument back in the first spot

This will handle `{}` oddities more readily, since we let vim do the complex nested-matching for us (regular expressions aren't powerful enough).

Realistically, I would record a macro (probably with trial and error):

```
qq0f{di{;vi{p%,pq
```

and then do

```
global/\\operation{e_/normal! @q
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the thorough explanation of how the command works!